# PostgreSQL: Trigger makes read operation slower

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, triggers

I am using PostgreSQL version 11.11.

I have a trigger which collects data from 5 different related tables (let's say t1, t2, t3, t4, t5) and inserts it into another table (let's say t6). The trigger starts after insert, delete and update against tables t4 and t5. There are more than 1 million rows in each table. I expected that execution of trigger could take time, but even the read operation (select-query) from tables t1,t2,t3 (not from tables t4, t5) takes much more time than it was before trigger created (it's three-four times slower now).

Can the triggers affect read operation (select-query)? Do the triggers influence on tables without triggers?

Comment: "*Can the triggers affect read operation*" - no

Comment: You only have so much CPU, disk, network, RAM available.  Your selects have to share those resources with the trigger execution.

Comment: Thank you @jjanes! I found that there were insert operations in background which slowed down the database